# Find String and assign a variable in a Batch Script

Tags: batch-file, variables, find

I am sure this is an easy one for you guys but I have been struggling with it.

The following code will go through the WMIC and export the line to a txt file then Set the var as Y
Here is where I am lost.
I need to set it up so if it exist, it will assign a variable to the entire line that was exported
Example: Microsoft Office Professional Plus 2016                                  16.0.4266.1001

So that when the entire script is done, I man make command window pop up that says:
Microsoft Office Professional Plus 2016                                  16.0.4266.1001
if installed and if not, the variable will say "Not installed."
This is to run on new laptops as a checking tool.

Thanks everyone

```
  @ Echo off
del C:\Temp\Cylance.txt
wmic product get name,version | find "Cisco AnyConnect Secure">>c:\temp\Cylance.txt & SET CISCO=Y
wmic product get name,version | find "Microsoft Office Professional">>c:\temp\Cylance.txt & sET Office=Y
wmic product get name,version | find "Microsoft Edge">>c:\temp\Cylance.txt & Set Edge=Y
wmic product get name,version | find "Cylance Unified Agent">>c:\temp\Cylance.txt & Set Cylance=Y
wmic product get name,version | find "Java">>c:\temp\Cylance.txt & Set Java=Y
wmic product get name,version | find "MultiPresenter">>c:\temp\Cylance.txt & Set Multi=Y

Echo %Cisco%
Echo %Office%
Echo %Edge%
Echo %Cylance%
Echo %Java%
Echo %Multi%
Pause
```

Comment: The first thing I'll ask is, are you aware that Win32_Product is not recommended to be used, because in enumerating it also performs checks, and could in doing so, make changes, to the system and take a long time to run. It is even more important therefore, if you do decide to ignore that recommendation, that you do not run it six times, when just one WMIC command can do that. Also Win32_Product only lists products installed using Windows installer, so unless all of those specific products were installed using that, they will not return results even if they are installed on the target system.

Comment: This is what I was able to work with at the time. I have tried other methods but I can not get it to work just right....  I am open to suggestions. I can rewrite if someone can point me in the right direction. I can do the work....

Comment: Replace each `&` (which means "and then") to `&&` (which means "if successful then"). Also possible: `wmic ... |find ... && set "var=Y" || set "var=N"